# django Import-export. How can I check if one of the sku wish are going to be imported exist, that way it not going to create a new product but updated

Tags: django

#admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Product
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

class ProductResource(resources.ModelResource):
class Meta:
model = Product

class ProductAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, admin.ModelAdmin):
search_fields = ['name','sku','parent','family']
list_display = ('id','sku','manufacturer','name','short_description','cost','price','price2','parent','family','nla',)
list_filter = ('manufacturer',)
resource_class = ProductResource

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)

Comment: If you add the **unique** attr to that field in the models, `sku = models.Charfield(max_length=6001, unique=True)`, the admin will catch the duplicate and not create another one- it won't do an update tho, not sure how you could do that easily + w/o writing a custom admin form

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.